# For n even, Fermat's Last Theorem has no Twin Pythagorean Triples.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

*This is my first naïve attempt at stating and proving a Lemma. Is it valid? Thanks!*

---

**Definitions.**
*[Twin Pythagorean Triple](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPythagoreanTriple.html)*. A Pythagorean Triple (a,b,c) for which two values are consecutive integers. Some examples are $(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (7, 24, 25),...$

*[Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)*. For any integer n > 2, the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ has no positive integer solutions.

*[Mihăilescu's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)*. The integers $2^3$ and $3^2$ are two powers of natural numbers whose values ($8$ and $9$, respectively) are consecutive. The theorem states that this is the only case of two consecutive powers.

**Rules.**
Assuming FLT has not yet been proved!

**Lemma.**
For $n$ even, *Fermat's Last Theorem* has no *Twin Pythagorean Triple*s.

**Proof.**
 Let $n = 2k$ $(k \in \mathbb N, k>1)$

$a^n+b^n=c^n$

can be expressed as

$(a^k)^2+(b^k)^2=(c^k)^2$

Notice the Pythagorean Triple

$(a^k,b^k,c^k)$

*Assume* Twin Triple, then

$(b^k-a^k = 1)$ or $(c^k-b^k = 1)$

resulting in pairs of two consecutive powers

$(a^k,b^k)$ or $(b^k,c^k)$

However, by *Mihăilescu's Theorem*, the only case of two consecutive powers is

$(2^3,3^2)$

Consequently

$(b^k-a^k > 1)$ or $(c^k-b^k > 1)$

Therefore, no Twin Triple exists for $k>1$. $\square$

---

Comment: why is it safe to assume all solutions to fermat's last theorem have to be of the form $(b^k-a^k=1)$ or $c^k-b^k=1)$

Comment: Better to write out the definition of TPT in the body of the question, than to make users chase it offsite.

Comment: Good idea. I've updated the question to include the TPT and FLT definitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$FLT$ having already been proved it is clear that this is not possible. Then by "rule of the game" we assume that $FLT$ has not yet been proved.
$$(x^n)^2+(y^n)^2=(z^n)^2$$
By definition we want that $y^n-x^n=1$ or $z^n-y^n=1$. This is trivially impossible because
$$y^n-x^n=(y-x)P(x,y)\\z^n-y^n=(z-y)Q(z,y)$$
Do we need more explanation? I have not understood the problem?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming that FLT has not yet been proved. Your trivial solution is probably the best (I'm not sure), but my main idea was to state and prove something. Did it succeed or fail? ;)

Comment: Your proof  is correct without doute but not necessary  Mihăilescu's Theorem (Catalan conjecture) because there is a another simple way.